# Change scrollTop offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and have a fullscreen hero unit at the top of my page, below that is my navigation. I have some js which allows my navbar to stick to be fixed at the top after you scroll past the full screen hero. Also some js for my smooth scrolling links.

The problem is the offset is different before you scroll past the full screen hero and after. But it works fine when you are past the jumbotron. I have tried a bunch of different things but I can seem to get this to work exactly.

[**Check out the fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/kDE3A/2/)

Here is my js for the smooth scrolling links:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // navigation click actions 
    $('.scroll-link').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var sectionID = $(this).attr("data-id");
        scrollToID('#' + sectionID, 750);
    });
    // scroll to top action
    $('.scroll-top').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1200);       
    });
    // mobile nav toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#main-nav').toggleClass("open");
    });
});
// scroll function
function scrollToID(id, speed){
    var offSet = 95;
    var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
    var mainNav = $('#main-nav');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset}, speed);
    if (mainNav.hasClass("open")) {
        mainNav.css("height", "1px").removeClass("in").addClass("collapse");
        mainNav.removeClass("open");
    }
}
if (typeof console === "undefined") {
    console = {
        log: function() { }
    };
}
```

By changing `var offSet = 95;` I am able to adjust the offset but what would be the best way to use 180 before the navbar sticks to the top but 95 when it does?

Also here is the js I am using for my navbar:

```
$(function () {
/*    $(".navbar-fixed-top").css({"top":$(".jumbotron").height()});

    $(window).resize(function (e) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css({"top":$(".jumbotron").height()});
    });*/
    $(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
        console.log('scroll top : ' + $(window).scrollTop());
        if($(window).scrollTop()>=$(".jumbotron").height())
        {
             $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
        }

        if($(window).scrollTop()<$(".jumbotron").height())
        {
             $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Still looking at the code, but one thing I might add, is don't forget a scroll indicator. Because you changed the style of the navbar, and fill the wallpaper to the viewport, I had no idea there was content beyond the top of the page. Lol Source code showed me, then I was clued in and scrolled down. It's not noticeable. Maybe a little `Scroll Down` white text fading in and out on the bottom left or right that disappears when the user scrolls.

Comment: @WASasquatch I've had that on my list since I started working on the hero lol hopefully ill get it done today!

Comment: Awesome. I just thought I was on the wrong page haha.

Comment: Also, I do not see this padding reduced by 100. I see the nav shift to the right by about 10px, and the content begin scrolling.

Comment: Did you check out the second link? The first link is without the margin fix

Comment: That's what the `-100px` is doing.

Comment: Well when you click a link in the nav it is offsetting the spacing between the title and navbar, but also reducing the spacing between the first section and navbar at the top, before the navbar "snaps" to the top that is my issue. Or I there is another extremely simple fix which I am missing.

Comment: @ve1jdramas SO is meant to be useful also for future visitors. By just pasting images and a link to a site that might go down one day does not fit the SO rules on http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan updated with fiddle and cleaned up a little, thank you.

Comment: This is not against any rule, however. SO only suggests examples via JSFiddle. Live site examples are fine _if_  JSFiddle is not a viable option to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WASasquatch You're quite new to SO. SO cannot rely on external links. Questions on SO should be accompanied by the **properly formatted, minimal code to fully reproduce the issue**. Even asking Q with just a Fiddle link will disable submit unless code is presented in the Question. You can find more info here: [help]

Comment: That has little to do with my comment. And you don't know if I'm new, or if I regulararily turncate my main email addresses and usernames.

Comment: While it is true he posted no code that has nothing to do with his choice in links or examples.

Comment: I posted no code because I don't know what code is relevant to the issue, as I dont know what is causing it! If I knew where the issue was coming from I would gladly provide code.

Comment: It's ok, @ve1jdramas this is one of those issues that could be one of many issues, which is why your website is a valid source for this question, as jsfiddle will not properly reproduce the issue. As it currently stands your JSFiddle has more padding and margining then the question you asked because of the constraining of the iframe. Which makes it harder to fix your problem on your main website. However, posting your CSS, whether the full sheet, or the elements in question, may help us.

Comment: I updated the question with any code I thought was relevant also added the full site link back in there, just want to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you open to angular.js? I have a directive i use for this. As seen [here](http://www.mtvtravelco.com/).

I'll grab the plunker link for you. you might find the code helpful.

Essentially you need to create a ghost dom element to take the place of the menu when you pull it to an new layout position.

EDIT: [Here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/6kdHNi9g8yawSHkQS0vY)

I won't suggest grabbing angular just for this. But you can use the basis of the events and logic to build your own solution.

This here is creating an element and placing in its place

```
$scope.spacer = $element.after(
    '<div class="spacer" style="height:' + $element[0].clientHeight + 'px">&nbsp;</div>').next();
```

then this element is removed when the menu is back to its static position.

Inspect the dom and watch how it changes, this will probably help you see the events and changes that need to take place.

EDIT 2 SOLUTION:

[HERE is the concepts applied to your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4M4QG/2/)

Comment: Yes definitely, if you can guide me to a tutorial or anything that can  help! I am a novice in javascript, but with some examples etc I should be ok!

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the plunker link and a short code snip from where the ghost element is added.

Comment: I believe this a little above my level, I am considering changing the layout at this point, I cant even figure it out from the plnkr!

Comment: @ve1jdramas I have forked and fixed your JSFiddle

Comment: Holy crap I cant believe you got it!!!!!! Ok give me 15 mins let me go over it and bounty is yours!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution but by adding `margin: 0 0 -100px 0;` to your `.navbar`you lose the spacing issue.

Also you're getting 22 console errors because of missing images. I'm not saying that this is causing any major problems but you would be better off losing them.

Comment: Ok this does work, but I feel like it's going to break something else lol I'll come back if it does! The console errors are because of wrong image paths, I keep moving the site and the plugin I am using requires full urls. Thank you Martin.

Comment: Ok so I did run into an issue, this causes the spacing on the first section below the navbar to have 100 less padding, [check it out here](http://aliensix.com/mytheme/) if you look at the spacing above "we create usable ui" any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you have not scrolled past the hero, navigation is still part of the layout and pushes content bellow it a little lower. When you scroll past (either manually or via a script) the hero, navigation is removed and fix positioned. That **makes everything which was bellow to "jump up"** exactly of the navigation height.

That means if portfolio was `1000px` from the top, on click you say: go `1000px` from top; but then porfolio moves `100px` up (as explained above) meaning it is now `900px` from the top while the window scrolled `1000px` as you asked.

When you have scrolled past the hero, nothing changes its position.

Comment: Can I have a hint as far as the code fix? I am understanding the problem now I believe but am having trouble adjusting it accordingly.